# testing custom ASP.NET membership provider

Tags: nhibernate, membership-provider

I'm using custom asp.net membership provider with underlaying nhibernate data access code, which is fine. Now I need to exercise these methods using tests.

Anyone interested in suggesting how these methods should be tested? with providing some links explaining test methods using some standars maybe ?

This is my first question so be gentle :)

Comment: have you tried this? http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2007/12/30/118071.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to unit testing any code that does something with the database or a 3rd party library you should de-couple these dependencies so that your tests only test your code.

For example, if we have a method in our membership provider for adding a single user, what we want to be testing is that our code for this single method works correctly and not that the database is up and running or that methods called by this method work. Our unit test should still pass even if the database is offline or if method calls on other classes fail.

This is where Mocking comes into play. You'll want to mock out your data context and set up any methods you'll be using on it so that you can control its response.

Look closely at the methods you have in your membership provider. What should each one do? That's the only thing you really want to test. Does this method, as a standalone unit, do the job I'm expecting it to.

Comment: I was thinking to test my methods inside membership provider without mocking, like, adding new user to db Table using CreateUser method, rolling back transaction to leave db as it was before testing. Is this approach I should be follow ? Mocking to strange to me :)

Comment: Personally I think mocking is a more efficient approach. If you're inserting and rolling back data in your database then you're not just testing your unit of code, you're testing the network, the network connection, the database engine, etc etc. When I write unit tests I want confidence that my code works as I expect it and I don't expect my tests to fail if the network is down.

Comment: ok, mocking it is :) Any links with concrete examples for mocking membership provider

Answer (score 0):

Membership providers are pretty difficult to mock and test, so personally I don't bother. What I do however is place all my membership code in classes that *are* easily testable.

Most of my custom providers look something like this:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public ButlinsMembershipProvider()
        {
            _userService = DI.Resolve<IUserService>();
        }

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return _userService.Authenticate(username, password);
        }
}
```

In this example, I would write integration tests to verify the behavior of the user service. I don't test the provider.